# How do I get a byobu session with a command to run on startup?

Tags: byobu

I am trying to get Byobu to startup with Ubuntu Server 12.04 when the server starts up.

I've figured out how to do this with a screen session but I want it to be in *Byobu* with all the added features, not in screen.

in `start()` within an init.d script for screen this is the line that works (after changing the environment to the correct user via `su - $USER -c "$USER_INIT; $1" >/dev/null && return 0` --- USER and USER_INIT are both populated properly, tested working via screen):

```
screen -U -S $SESSIONNAME -d -t $WCAPP -m $WCAPP
```

replacing `screen` with `byobu` or `byobu-screen` does not work.  I have the back-end set to screen.

I DO NOT want to edit the `/.byobu/windows` file as that does not launch until a user manually starts a byobu back-end.

The $SESSIONNAME I am using is weechat and the $WCAPP variable is weechat-curses, I have no quarrels about using the literal value instead of passing variables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Open your terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and then type as

```
nano /etc/rc.local
```

and then add this line before exit 0

```
byobu -S boot-time mycommand &
```

Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> save & close.

Comment: I tried using this with rtorrent but it didn't work, is there any way I can find out what went wrong?