# Start byobu setup with server reboot

Tags: screen, startup, restart, byobu

I would like to start my byobu setup at a server reboot. With screen I use the rc.local and do it like this:

```
su user -c 'screen -dmS screenname sh /home/user/start.sh'
```

Now I would like to know how I do this with byobu that the screens are in the right order and have a custom name I give them.

I know there is already this post, but it doesn´t answer my question and I couldn´t find a solution by googleing it:
[How do I get a byobu session with a command to run on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274597/how-do-i-get-a-byobu-session-with-a-command-to-run-on-startup)

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu
this command enables byobu as your default TTY

> byobu-enable